# Oracle Function ORA-00904 invalid indentifier

Tags: oracle

I'm having trouble with my Oracle function, which is giving me the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SCORING.F_BONITETA2", line 11
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Obviously, the A in `decode(a.boniteta, A, 1, 2)` is causing this error. I tried to use 'A' and "A", respectively, but I get an error in both cases, when I try to compile function. Any help appreciated.

Here is my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_BONITETA2
(
    dav in varchar2,
    tip in number
) 
RETURN number
IS
   sco number;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'select score 
     from sco_sif_score
     where sif_kat = 12
     and tip_pod = :tip
     and vrednost in
                  (select decode(a.boniteta, A, 1, 2)
                   from sco_boniteta a
                   inner join 
                      (select distinct a.par_davcna, a.par_reg
                       from scoring_gvin a) b
                   on a.maticna = b.par_reg
                   where b.par_davcna = :dav)'
     INTO sco USING tip, dav; 
     EXCEPTION 
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
   END;
   RETURN sco;
END F_BONITETA2;
```

Comment: Are you having an error in compilation or execution? Also, is A both the alias of the table and a column of the table sco_boniteta? Or is it a constant value 'A'? Also, why do you need dynamic SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Aleksej. I get an error in execution if I use A without quotes (compiles ok). If I use quotes ('A' or "A" I get an error in compilation: `Error(17,37): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "A" when expecting one of the following...` Aliases are not the problem, I believe. And A is value, not column name. Column is a.boniteta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to use a `decode` on the `'A'` string and the issue is in escaping the quotes within dynamic code.

The point could be that you do not need dynamic SQL at all, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_BONITETA2(dav IN VARCHAR2, tip IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    sco                                     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT score
          INTO sco
          FROM sco_sif_score
         WHERE     sif_kat = 12
               AND tip_pod = tip
               AND vrednost IN (SELECT DECODE(a.boniteta, 'A', 1, 2)
                                  FROM sco_boniteta a
                                       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.par_davcna, a.par_reg
                                                     FROM scoring_gvin a) b
                                           ON a.maticna = b.par_reg
                                 WHERE b.par_davcna = dav);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            NULL;
    END;

    RETURN sco;
END F_BONITETA2;
```

Also, accordig to Boneist's comment, if you do not need the BEGIN...END block for some other reason, this could be a way to rewrite your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_BONITETA2(dav IN VARCHAR2, tip IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    sco                                     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT score
      INTO sco
      FROM sco_sif_score
     WHERE     sif_kat = 12
           AND tip_pod = tip
           AND vrednost IN (SELECT DECODE(a.boniteta, 'A', 1, 2)
                              FROM sco_boniteta a
                                   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.par_davcna, a.par_reg
                                                 FROM scoring_gvin a) b
                                       ON a.maticna = b.par_reg
                             WHERE b.par_davcna = dav);
    RETURN sco;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        return NULL;   
END F_BONITETA2;
```

In general, these could be a couple of ways to handle a string containing a quote by doubling the quotes or by the means of the [alternative quoting method](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Literals.htm#SQLRF00217):

```
SQL> select 'This is a quote '' and these are two quotes ''''.' from dual UNION ALL
  2  select q'[This is a quote ' and these are two quotes ''.]' from dual;

'THISISAQUOTE''ANDTHESEARETWOQUOTES''''.'
----------------------------------------------
This is a quote ' and these are two quotes ''.
This is a quote ' and these are two quotes ''.
```

Comment: In addition to your comments and proposed solution, I'd also question the need to have the extra begin/end in the code; this could all be done in one block if the exception handler returns null when the no_data_found exception occurs.

Comment: @Flin - Obviously, `'A'` is the correct value to compare to (you are comparing to a string), so why didn't that work? Aleksej hinted to it at the top of his Answer: because it was all within a long quoted string (the text of the query you wanted to `execute immediate`). To have a single-quote in a quoted string (a string literal), you need to use TWO single-quotes, not a double-quote! You needed to compare to `''A''` - which is the only thing you **didn't** try. Note how this is different from `"A"` (with one double-quote character on each side).

Comment: @Aleksej You understood well :). It's working as expected now. Thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: @Flin I showed you what Boneist was suggesting. You are probably missing the return in the exception handling part

Comment: @Aleksej if only I could upvote again for your additions to your answer!

Comment: @Aleksej Thank you very much. Your reply clarifies what Boneist tried to explain. Yes, when I deleted extra begin/end I didn't move return in front of exception, so exception triggered before reaching return. You're answer make me realize that. Thanks again, to both of you.

Comment: Me too Boneist. I upvoted original answer, but it cannot be seen as I'm so new to StackOverFlow. Great job, Aleksej!

Comment: @mathguy You're absolutely right! I could have sworn I did try to enclose A within two single quotes, but I obviously didn't. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Flin you should [mark Aleksej's answer as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it has sorted your problem.

Comment: @Boneist Ah, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know that. I will do it for my other questions too.